# LateInitializationError: Field 'imageFile' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am working on an application where I capture images from a camera initialized and navigate to the next page. I am writing a method named captureImage and calling it in floatingactionbutton. Below is the code---

```
void _captureImage() async {
if (_cameraController != null && 
_cameraController.value.isInitialized) 
{
try {
  final image = await _cameraController.takePicture();
  if (image != null) {
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Verify(image: _image),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
} catch (e) {
  // handle the error here, e.g. print an error message
  print('Error capturing image: $e');
}
} else {
print("Camera not initialized.");
}
}
```

I have tried initializing

on the second screen i have used image to display in container.
below is that code---

this is how i initialized---

late File image;

```
child: Container(
width: 140,
height: 180,
child: Image.file(image),
 ),
```

error shows in this line.

Comment: it seems you are using `_imageFile` instead of `imageFile`

Comment: The code as written shouldn't be able to produce that error. There must be a `imageFile` variable somewhere else in your code with the `late` keyword. Also the `if (_imageFile != null) {` check is rather pointless because the line in front of it ensures that it never is `null`

Comment: i have modified the code to capture image using existing camera. But the app is crashing when i click the button. Why is that i am not able to capture image using takePicture().

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your variable like this if you are planning to assign it later

```
File? imageFile
```

OR

```
late File imageFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you iniinitialized the camera controller?

```
_cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);    
_cameraController.initialize();
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to recreate another variable, use the previous one you've defined:

```dart
 XFile? _imageFile;
  
  void _captureImage() async {
    if (!_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    _imageFile = await _cameraController.takePicture();
    print(_imageFile?.path);
    setState(() {
      if (_imageFile != null) {

        //if you like to convert it to File
        File file = File(_imageFile!.path);
        ....
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for response. But still it shows error. i have edited my code please have a look.

Comment: after modifying code, when i click to capture , app crashes, just comes out of the app

Comment: not sure, does it work if you comment `child: Image.file(image),`